# Beginner to API Json - Attempting to understand URL output

Tags: java, api, url, get, fme

I am using FME to get output from the following: https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/developers-guide

I am just a beginner and is first time I want to write this up. To generate an Output URL from this with the relevant columns, can anyone explain what I need to get the request URL. I am using GET as the HTTP method

An example of a url i get some data out of is - https://soa.smext.faa.gov/asws/api/airport/status/SFO

But when i try with the links below which i tested does not get any output https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure=%7B%22name%22:%22areaName%22%7D

Answer (score 1):

[`https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk//v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure={"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","areaCode":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"2020-07-07","cumCasesByPublishDate":"2020-08-08","newDeathsByDeathDate":"2020-02-06","cumDeathsByDeathDate":"2020-06-09"}`](https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk//v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure=%7B%22date%22:%22date%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%222020-07-07%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%222020-08-08%22,%22newDeathsByDeathDate%22:%222020-02-06%22,%22cumDeathsByDeathDate%22:%222020-06-09%22%7D)

Comment: Explaining the answer to the question poster should be much more helpful to them

Answer (score 1):

This is a better link for you to try out.

[https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure={%22date%22:%22date%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22,%22newDeaths28DaysByDeathDate%22:%22newDeaths28DaysByDeathDate%22}](https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure=%7B%22date%22:%22date%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22,%22newDeaths28DaysByDeathDate%22:%22newDeaths28DaysByDeathDate%22%7D)

Took me a while to suss it out.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.